# mapper_parsing_exception while import dashboard to kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

When I import a dashboard from kibana 7.5.1 to kibana 7.4.1, it failed with error "the file could not be processed". I call kibana import object api on kibana dev tool console instead, and it provide following response:

```
POST /api/saved_objects/_import
{
  "file" : "C:\Users\dashboards-kibana\EKC-Dashboard-Prod.ndjson"
}

{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "failed to parse"
      }
    ],
    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason": "failed to parse",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "json_parse_exception",
      "reason": "Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@33da7471; line: 2, column: 17]"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

This is my first time work with kibana. Is there anyway to solve the import error?

Comment: Try double slash ( C:\\ ... )

Comment: According to the error message the file seems to be uploaded. But the content can not be processed

Comment: @Paulo is that help if I conver the ndjson to valid json format?

Comment: No it would not.